# Resize Object element to its container element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a `<object>` element on the page, I want to set the object's width to its container element's width, and then I want to set the object's height to its own height. How do I do that?

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/C4qa3gYE7fi8u7qjz5Ds?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'width:auto' on your object element, try using 'width:100%' instead.

```
angular.element("#dataloader").html('<object data="http://www.w3schools.com/" style="width:100%;height:auto" />');
```

Comment: I updated plunker with your suggestion, it looks better, but the height is still not adjusted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as setting the object's width as `width:auto` and then set object's height as your wish for example `height:100px`.

Usually `auto` tag adjusts itself based on the other elements `px` given. . And `width:auto` is usually used for landscapes and `height:auto` for profile pics (This tip is not any standard but based on my experience)